# The format of encrypted password in `/etc/shadow`

Tags: encryption, shadow

I see a hashed passphrase like the following in `/etc/shadow`. I don't quite understand its format.

```
$y$j9T$F5Jx5fExrKuPp53xLKQ..1$X3DX6M94c7o.9agCG9G317fhZg9SqC.5i5rd.RhAtQ7
```

It is made of four parts as shown below. According to `crypt(5)`, `y` means `yescrypt`.

https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/libcrypt-dev/crypt.5.en.html

```
- y
- j9T
- F5Jx5fExrKuPp53xLKQ..1
- X3DX6M94c7o.9agCG9G317fhZg9SqC.5i5rd.RhAtQ7
```

What is the meaning of the last three parts?

Comment: Hard to believe that many distributions have switched to yescript as the default hashing algorithm, and none of them describe the `param` part, or why `j9T` is used there and why and what it means.

Comment: [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/724514/451115) is an answer I provided to another, similar, question on the topic. It takes a deep dive of the `yescrypt` format and includes each of the fields.

Answer (score 15):

The answer to "What is the meaning of the parts of the [`crypt(3)`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/libcrypt-dev/crypt.3.en.html) function":

- `id`
- `param`
- `salt`
- `hash`

As explained more in detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#Key_derivation_functions_supported_by_crypt).

Regarding the new `yescrypt` "passphrase hashing scheme", the meaning of the second field can be understood by reading [this](https://blog.filippo.io/the-scrypt-parameters/), and if you want even more information, you can also read the [yescrypt v2 specification](https://www.password-hashing.net/submissions/specs/yescrypt-v2.pdf).

I did some more research, and it seems that the hashing is happening in the function [yescrypt_r](https://sources.debian.org/src/libxcrypt/1:4.4.18-2/lib/alg-yescrypt-common.c/#L323-L477). You can see the different parameters definitions in the code.
In the case the `id` is `7`, `N` is set to `2^x` where `x` is the number in the first digit of `param`, and then r and p are both parsed using the function [`decode64_uint32_fixed`](https://sources.debian.org/src/libxcrypt/1:4.4.18-2/lib/alg-yescrypt-common.c/#L190-L206) from the rest of the `param` field.
In all other cases (i.e. only when `id` is `y`, since the function checks the value of `id` and returns if it isn't `7` or `y`), the source conditionally sets various different parameters, with a block of code written in such a way that I feel trying to understand it would go against the wishes of the original author. So I leave it as an exercise for the reader.

In that same file, The function [yescrypt](https://sources.debian.org/src/libxcrypt/1:4.4.18-2/lib/alg-yescrypt-common.c/#L479-L493) that follows it exposes a simpler interface, similar to the one of `crypt(3)`.

Comment: So as far as I understand it, the password is hashed not encrypted.

Comment: I don't see which sentence in crypt(3) explains the four parts. Could you showed me the exact sentence that you refer to? Also, the filippo.io blog is not well written. I don't know what r N P  refer to in my example.

Comment: @not2savvy indeed, AFAIR, the name `crypt` comes from the word "cryptography", in its broad sense, and was not meant to imply there was any reversible encryption happening.

Comment: @user15502206 the sentence that explains the four parts isn't in the man, but in the Wikipedia link. man pages are written by people who are perfectly familiar about a topic for people who are perfectly familiar about that topic; so for learning, I'd rank their value lower than the actual source code. The exact sentence is: "The format is defined as: `$<id>[$<param>=<value>(,<param>=<value>)*][$<salt>[$<hash>]] `". The filippo.io blog only details the logical scrypt parameters, not how the `yescrypt` ones are implemented in `crypt(3)`. So, it is useful, but not directly.

Comment: @not2savvy, yep, you don't encrypt passwords, since it's not necessary to turn them back to plain text, so you _don't_ want that to be easily done. See e.g. https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/118457

Comment: That obfuscated encoding of the parameters almost feels like a good reason not to use that hash...

Comment: @not2savvy The very first version of `crypt()` actually did encrypt a fixed string with your password, hence this name which does not reflect today's processing.

Comment: Hi, do you know what j9T means? Are there other available options in this field? Detailed materials of yescrypt lacks...

Comment: *"I feel trying to understand it would go against the wishes of the original author"*. Do you mean the algorithm and configuration parameters are intentionally *obfuscated*?