# What does j9T mean in yescrypt (from /etc/shadow)?

Tags: encryption, shadow

Consider this Shadow string

```
$y$j9T$PaFEMV0mbpeadmHDv0Lp31$G/LliR3MqgdjEBcFC1E.s/3vlRofsZ0Wn5JyZHXAol5
```

There are 4 parts

- id : y (yescrypt)
- param : j9T
- salt : PaFEMV0mbpeadmHDv0Lp31
- hash : G/LliR3MqgdjEBcFC1E.s/3vlRofsZ0Wn5JyZHXAol5

**Q:**

1. What does `j9T` in param field mean?
2. Are there other options in this field?
3. Where can we find official documentation?

I've seen this question; [The format of encrypted password in `/etc/shadow`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/642570/70178), however, there is no explanation there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Disclaimer

Below are my own findings and the way I interpreted them without having an expert understanding of cryptography and the concepts involved.

### Signatures

Notably, as the [`yescrypt` `CHANGES` file](https://github.com/openwall/yescrypt/blob/main/CHANGES) on the OpenWall GitHub states about the *Changes made between 0.8.1 (2015/10/25) and 1.0.0 (2018/03/09)*, *`yescrypt` has two signatures*:

- `$7$` - classic `scrypt` hashes, not very compact *fixed-length encoding*
- `$y$` - native `yescrypt` and classic `scrypt` hashes, new extremely compact *variable-length encoding*

This extremely compact *variable-length encoding* is what introduces much but not all of the complexity that the end of the second-to-last paragraph in [this UNIX StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/642571) talks about.

### Parameters

For a simple description of the parameters, the [BitcoinWiki Yescrypt parameters](https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Yescrypt#Yescrypt_parameters%22) section can be helpful:

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `password` | password to hash |
| `salt` | salt to use |
| `flags` | flags to toggle features |
| `N` | increasing N increases running time and memory use |
| `r` | increasing R increases the size of blocks operated on by the algorithm (and thus increases memory use) |
| `p` | parallelism factor |
| `t` | increasing T increases running time without increasing memory use |
| `g` | the number of times the hash has been "upgraded", used for strengthening stored password hashes without requiring knowledge of the original password |
| `NROM` | read-only memory that the resulting key will be made to depend on |
| `DKLen` | the length of key to derive (output) |

### Format

Of these, `$7$` hashes only use the following:

- `N` - encoded with 1 byte (character)
- `r` - encoded with 5 bytes (characters)
- `p` - encoded with 5 bytes (characters)

Since `$7$` also means *fixed-length encoding*, every parameter has a prespecified number of bytes that encode it and every one of the parameters comes in order: `$7$Nrrrrrppppp$`...`$`.

Let's enclose each byte in `[]` square brackets: `$7$[N][r1][r2][r3][r4][r5][p1][p2][p3][p4][p5]$`...`$`. Further, this means 11 is the exact number of bytes required (hence why it's *not compact*) for parameters in the sequence specified.

On the other hand, `$y$` hashes require three parameters:

- `flags` - encoded with at least 1 byte (character)
- `N` - encoded with at least 1 byte (character)
- `r` - encoded with at least 1 byte (character)

Still, `$y$` hashes can use all parameters by encoding them with *variable-length*. Effectively, this means each parameter is prefixed with its own size *#* encoded in the first byte and continues with *#* bytes:

`$y$[flags_len=#][flags1]`...`[flags#][N_len=#][N1]`...`[N#][r_len=#][r1]`...`$`...`$`

To make things even more complex, the mandatory parameters are followed by an optional [`have`](https://github.com/openwall/yescrypt/blob/main/yescrypt-common.c#L375) parameter. Based on the value of `have`, *yescrypt* decides **which, if any** of `p`, `t`, `g`, and `NROM` are also part of the supplied data.

For comprehensive guidelines about the parameters and which ones to use in what situations, it's probably best to consult the [`yescrypt` `PARAMETERS` file](https://github.com/openwall/yescrypt/blob/main/PARAMETERS) on the OpenWall GitHub.

### Encoding

Decoding the parameter fields is done via [`decode64_uint32()`](https://github.com/openwall/yescrypt/blob/main/yescrypt-common.c#L100), which uses an [array](https://github.com/openwall/yescrypt/blob/main/yescrypt-common.c#L45), [indexed](https://github.com/openwall/yescrypt/blob/main/yescrypt-common.c#L106) by [`atoi64()`](https://github.com/openwall/yescrypt/blob/main/yescrypt-common.c#L92) with the difference between the ASCII values of the current byte and the `.` period character (46), which is the base:

```c
atoi64_partial[77] = {
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
  64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
  12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
  25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37,
  64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
  38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
  51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63
};
```

For each field, starting from the first field byte `yescrypt` performs the following actions:

1. Use the first field byte to [index the array](https://github.com/openwall/yescrypt/blob/main/yescrypt-common.c#L106) as described above.
2. Perform calculations with the array item to get a [partial value for the field](https://github.com/openwall/yescrypt/blob/main/yescrypt-common.c#L110-L119).
3. Perform calculations with the array item to get the [number of following bytes](https://github.com/openwall/yescrypt/blob/main/yescrypt-common.c#L115) that encode the rest of the field value.
4. For each **next byte**, the algorithm uses it to [index the array again](https://github.com/openwall/yescrypt/blob/main/yescrypt-common.c#L122) and [adds the data](https://github.com/openwall/yescrypt/blob/main/yescrypt-common.c#L126) to reach the final field value.

There is some pseudo-code for other processes in the [BitcoinWiki Yescrypt functions](https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Yescrypt#Functions) section.

### Demo Parameter Encoding

Let's take an example from the `PARAMETERS` file above:

- `flags = YESCRYPT_DEFAULTS`
- `N = 4096`
- `r = 32`
- `p = 1`
- `t = 0`
- `g = 0`
- `NROM = 0`

The above set of values is described as a standard *Large and slow (memory usage 16 MiB, performance like bcrypt cost 2^8 - latency 10-30 ms and throughput 1000+ per second on a 16-core server)* choice for *Password hashing for user authentication, no ROM*.

`$y$` is the signature.

`flags = YESCRYPT_DEFAULT = 182 = 0xB6 = j` in *`yescrypt` variable-length encoding*.

Here, `flags` should decode to `YESCRYPT_DEFAULT`, which is equivalent to `YESCRYPT_RW_DEFAULTS`, defined as `(YESCRYPT_RW | YESCRYPT_ROUNDS_6 | YESCRYPT_GATHER_4 | YESCRYPT_SIMPLE_2 | YESCRYPT_SBOX_12K)`:

- `YESCRYPT_RW = 0x002`
- `YESCRYPT_ROUNDS_6 = 0x004`
- `YESCRYPT_GATHER_4 = 0x010`
- `YESCRYPT_SIMPLE_2 = 0x020`
- `YESCRYPT_SBOX_12K = 0x080`

Performing the *logical `OR`* operation, `yescrypt` arrives at the final number and encodes it.

`N = 4096 = 0x1000 = 9` in *`yescrypt` variable-length encoding*. In fact, *N = 2<sup>decoded_N_field</sup>*.

`r = 32 = 0x20 = T` in *`yescrypt` variable-length encoding*.

`$` at this point tells `yescript` that no optional parameters were specified.

Finally, the *salt* is added. It is theoretically of arbitrary length. However, ***the salt must be of a length that's a power of 4***.

`$y$j9T$SALT$`

### Examples

Here are a couple of valid but not secure examples, which may be visually helpful after the descriptions above:

- `$7$9/..../..../$SALTS$`
- `$y$./.$SALT$`
- `$y$8/.$SALT$`